Spring Security error Like Stopping service [Tomcat] and Error creating bean with name 'springSecurity'
I have created new project and when I am created the new spring security class  I am getting the error and also added the spring security dependency please go through the code and I think this info is enough.
While i try to run the program it shows an error saying like:
Error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurity': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-18T18:36:31.217+05:30 ERROR 16888 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurity': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    

This is my Spring Security class
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SpringSecurity {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/journal/**", "/user/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .build();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}     

This is my POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.engineeringdigest</groupId>
    <artifactId>journalApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JournalApp</name>
    <description>Application for Journals</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

<dependency>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


For starters stop mixing versions. You are mixing Spring Boot 3.1 and 3.2 jars. Next your @Autowired method doesn't make sense in the configuration class nor is it needed.

To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. Did you?

Remove the entire configureGlobal function
